# Tracking progress of a lodash function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

In my code, I merge three "huge" datasets, about 3.5 million rows each. I use the code `return _.merge({}, oldestDataset, newerDatasets)` to do this. It takes about 5 minutes on my Macbook Air, which doesn't really matter, but I'd like to track the progress of this. Is it possible to know in advance how many cycles this function will take?

Comment: Unless you are calling `_.merge` in a different thread (web worker or another process using node) you wont be able to somehow report your progress until the very end.

Comment: Alright, thanks! If I were to summon a different thread, is it possible to report progress of each step, or just 0 or 100% as well?

Comment: Not with current `_.merge` implementation I guess.

Comment: This is very exotic requirement There's nothing really complex in _.merge, you can do the same thing in a way you like with for loop.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to remain up-to-date with lodash, and I want to actually use lodash because of their priority on performance (which I absolutely need with my huge datasets).

Comment: How big is your dataset?

Comment: You can't do that with Lodash. If you're after performance and need custom solution, spare some time on tailoring it. That's what all of us have to do from time to time. You will likely end up with asynchronous function that processes objects in chunks and returns a promise of merged data. Btw, reporting the progress in percents may be not a good idea here because calculating the number of keys in each object will take some time by itself. If there's a chance to not do this operation on client side, I would suggest to use it.

Comment: `merge()` can get expensive depending on what it's comparing - especially when it's repeated millions of times. @JeffHuijsmans, can you provide some samples of the two datasets you're merging?

Comment: Filling backlog of unanswered things: thanks guys, I ended up making a custom set of functions for this. I was lazy, heh. Thanks for all the feedback :)